# Converting postgres box to .Net NpgsqlBox

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am trying to connect to a postgres database and pull out a box data type and parse it into a NpgsqlBox.

I was hoping there would be a constructor such as:

```
    new NpgsqlBox(reader.GetString(0));
```

But cannot find anything. I could split the string manually and use another constructor:

```
    new NpgsqlBox(getUpperRight(reader.GetString(0)), getLowerLeft(reader.GetString(0)));
```

Although I'm hoping for a nicer solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure for any nonstandard datatype you can simply use `GetValue` and then cast it as the proper datatype:

```
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select * from my_box", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    NpgsqlBox b = (NpgsqlBox)reader.GetValue(0);
}

reader.Close();
```